# Phalconphp cookie getValue return null

Tags: php, cookies, phalcon

I need to store information into cookies, Phalcon sets the cookie correctly, but it will not return it, for example:

```
if(!$this->cookies->has('t')){
        $this->cookies->set('t', 'test', (10*(365*(24*(60*60))))+time(), '/', null, '*');
}
$c = $this->cookies->get('t');//when i dump this i can see cookie value as protected value
$c->getValue(); // but here i got null
```

As i decribe in comments in example, i got null when i call getValue, but why when i can see the value in dump ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Phalcon are you using ?

I'm on 2.0.3 and I use this :

```
$this->cookies->get('lang')->getValue()
```

which returns me the correct value :/

You store the returned object into $c but everything looks good for me when I see your code